# Function mixing up values of different model (within similar named fields)

Tags: django, django-views

Here is my search function

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET['query']
    allPoststit = List.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
    allPostscont = List.objects.filter(content__icontains=query)
    allPostsl = allPoststit.union(allPostscont)
    allPoststitm = MusicList.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
    allPostscontm = MusicList.objects.filter(content__icontains=query)
    allPostsm = allPoststitm.union(allPostscontm)
    allPoststitb = BookList.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
    allPostscontb = BookList.objects.filter(content__icontains=query)
    allPostsb = allPoststitb.union(allPostscontb)
    allPosts2 = allPostsl.union(allPostsm)
    allPosts = allPosts2.union(allPostsb)
    params = {'allPosts' : allPosts, 'query':query}
    return render(request, 'app/search.html', params)
```

when from template im calling

```
{% for tag in i.genre.all %}
<div class="Genre">
<small>{{ tag }}</small>
</div>
{% empty %}
            No tags!
{% endfor %}
```

Its mixing up values within different models or returning empty. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: `i.genre.all` what is `i` here? Plus you have multiple models which you seem to be querying but don't show any code for them... Please see [ask] and how to write a [mre], your question is lacking quite a lot of important context...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, not `allBlabla`, it is `all_blablabla`. And you don't even send some `"genre"` or `"i"` object to your context, you send `"allPosts`" and `"query"`, so why do you try to loop through something that does not exist in your context, in your template?

Comment: `def search(request): 
    genremovie = List.objects.all()  
    genremusic = MusicList.objects.all()  
    genrebook = BookList.objects.all()  
    params = {'allPosts' : allPosts, 'query':query, 'genremovie': genremovie, 'genremusic': genremusic, 'genrebook': genrebook}  
    return render(request, 'app/search.html', params)`

Comment: i have added these line to fetch genre . anyway I can fetch that relative to previous codes in my template? sorry just one month into backend dev. very little knowledge

Comment: Now you can loop through all of these objects in your template. For example: `{% for movie in genremovie %} {{ movie }} {% endfor %}`

Comment: thanks that really helped. I put some for and ifs in my template. and it worked like a charm.